# genindex and modindex footer links don't work in readthedocs.io

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext, read-the-docs, autodoc

I have a Python project using Sphinx for docs. I am building the docs remotely on readthedocs.io service.

I used `sphinx-quickstart` and it generated an `index.rst` file with these links in the footer:

```
Indices and tables
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

* :ref:`genindex`
* :ref:`modindex`
* :ref:`search`
```

When I push changes to readthedocs.io and build the docs, my build succeeds. Docs that I manually linked via `toctree` directive all work fine.

The `search` link works fine.

But the `genindex` link goes to an empty page, titled "Index"

And the `modindex` page links to `py-modindex.html`, which is a 404.

Following this guide: https://samnicholls.net/2016/06/15/how-to-sphinx-readthedocs I had run `sphinx-apidoc -o api-docs/ ../myproject` to generate the autodoc .rst files.

I linked the resulting `api-docs/modules.rst` in the `toctree` section at the top of my `index.rst`... That link works and if I click through the `api-docs` have been generated correctly.

Also generated by `sphinx-autodoc` were files for each package in my project, they contain directives like:

```
myproject.whatever module
-------------------------

.. automodule:: myproject.whatever
   :members:
   :undoc-members:
   :show-inheritance:
```

If I browse directly to these pages they have content, but they don't appear in the index (only the tocs they are manually linked in).

I also have some manually authored pages, again linked via toc.

My `docs/conf.py` looks like:

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath("../"))

extensions = [
    "sphinx.ext.autodoc",
    "sphinx.ext.viewcode",
    "sphinx.ext.napoleon",
    "sphinx_autodoc_typehints",
]

templates_path = ["_templates"]

exclude_patterns = ["_build", "Thumbs.db", ".DS_Store"]

html_theme = "alabaster"

html_static_path = ["_static"]
```

I believe the fact that html generated from the autodoc `.rst` stub files are filled with modules and classes extracted from the `.py` files in my project indicates that the sys path fix and autodoc are basically working.

So my question is:

- How to make `` :ref:`genindex` ``  have some content?
- How to fix `` :ref:`modindex` ``  points to `py-modindex.html` which does not exist?

Comment: `sphinx-autodoc` doesn't generate the `.rst` files, that's done by `sphinx-apidoc`. There are 2 main possibilites here, 1º you set something in your conf.py to not generate the index [for example html_use_index](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-html_use_index). Or, 2º you somehow broke your Sphinx (the index can stop working for indirect reasons, from errors that are elsewhere). For the 1st include your `conf.py` for the 2nd I'd advise generating a minimal test project with everything to default.

Comment: I am not using `sphinx-apidoc`, I have not set `html_use_index=False` in my `conf.py` and default is `True`

Comment: From your description the indexes should work (and that's the problem)!! So the cause of the problem is elsewhere. Edit your question to include the `conf.py` (just to make sure) and try creating a new project with 1 single `.py` module and 1 `.rst` besides the `modules.rst` and `index.rst` that are generated by `sphinx-quickstart`. Also, run `make clean` everytime before `make html`!

Comment: Hmm, I think the problem is readthedocs.io specific... if I `make clean` and `make html` locally then a `py-modindex.html` file is generated and `genindex.html` has content

Comment: You had not mentioned RTD before (I honestly don't know what the issue there might be). But the problem was solved locally by `make clean` because inconsistencies between successive builds without cleaning can break the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I eventually worked out in the comments, thanks to help from @bad_coder, my problem was specific to building the docs in readthedocs.io

Building the docs locally worked fine.

The reason came down to use of `sphinx.ext.autodoc`, perhaps in conjunction with `sphinx_autodoc_typehints`, which seems to need to import my actual python code. Checking the logs of my apparently successful readthedocs build showed actually there were warnings like:

```
WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'whatever' from module 'myproject'; the following exception was raised:
No module named 'somelib'
```

i.e the docs had only partially built, it had skipped the parts it couldn't do.

The build worked locally because I was already in a virtualenv with all my project's dependencies installed.

(IMHO this seems like a bad design of the `sphinx.ext.autodoc` and/or `sphinx_autodoc_typehints` ...good static-analysis tools exist for Python which can build an AST or CST and extract structure and docstrings without importing any code.)

Well anyway, this meant that I needed to tell readthedocs.io how to install all my project deps.  This is slightly complicated by the fact I'm using Poetry, which is not explicitly supported. This means I don't have a   `requirements.txt` file to point to (and I don't want to manually create one that is a duplicate of everything in my `pyproject.toml`).

Fortunately the `pyproject.toml` file is understandable by `pip`, so we're able to use the `pip install` method described here for readthedocs.io to install both my project deps, plus extra deps that are only needed for building docs: https://github.com/readthedocs/readthedocs.org/issues/4912#issuecomment-664002569

To summarise:

1. Deleted my `docs/requirements.txt`
2. Added:

   ```
   [tool.poetry.dependencies]
   ...
   sphinx = {version = "^3.1.1", optional = true}
   sphinx-autodoc-typehints ={version = "^1.11.1", optional = true}
   ```

   and:

   ```
   [tool.poetry.extras]
   docs = [
       "sphinx",
       "sphinx-autodoc-typehints"
   ]
   ```

   to my `pyproject.toml`
3. Updated my `.readthedocs.yml` to:

   ```yaml
   version: 2

   sphinx:
     configuration: docs/conf.py

   python:
     version: 3.8
     install:
       - method: pip
         path: .
         extra_requirements:
           - docs
   ```
4. Pushed these changes to readthedocs.io ...voilà, now it works.

Comment: I think it's best for future readers if you edit the question and state in the first line this problem was both local and also specific to using Poetry with RTD (adding the poetry tag would also be advisable). BTW, self-accepting the answer would also contribute towards keeping the tags tidy.

Answer (score 1):

`genindex` and `modindex` are automatically managed by Sphinx. Two cases should be considered:

1. Any declaration in a `.rst` file will be inserted in those indexes. For example, if you declare [a function](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/domains.html#directive-py-function) from the Python domain:

```
Your rst file
-------------

.. py:function:: name(parameters)
```

It will be inserted in the indexes even if it doesn't have a corresponding function in any `.py` file.

2. Using autodoc directives, the same applies with a few more rules. The autodoc extension will substitute domain declarations (like above) depending if the object has a docstring and if you are using the `:members:` and or `:undoc-members:` options. So you have to verify you are using the correct option and directive for your case.

```
Your rst file
-------------

.. autoclass:: Your_Module.Your_Class
   :members:
```

The above example will be substituted by a `:py:class::` domain declaration if the corresponding class has a docstring, if not you need to add the `:undoc-members:` option.

---

---

The symptoms you are describing of having empty indexes happens when you haven't declared anything in the `.rst` files. With the nuance that the autodoc directives may or may not do those declarations for you depending if the objects have docstrings and you used the right options in the directives.

---

---

**EDIT:** You should also run `make clean` before your builds (e.g.`make html`) because inconsistencies between builds can break the index.